# Google Sign In API: isSignedIn.get() returning inconsistent values

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-identity

I'm trying to check if a user is signed in or not, but I'm getting really inconsistent results that seem to have some sort of race condition involved.  I basically took the code [Google Developer Website](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners):

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });

  console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get());

  setTimeout(function(){console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get())},50);

  setTimeout(function(){console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get())},500);

  setTimeout(function(){console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get())},1000);
});
```

For some reason, the first two return false, and the second to return true.  I have double checked, and I am signed in, so it seems like the first two should be returning true.  What am I missing her?  I've looked at the documentation, and there doesn't seem to be anything that indicated something asynchronous happening, and I'm not sure what I should be waiting on before I can get a reliable result from the `isSignedIn` call.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe I missed it in the documentation somewhere (if I did, it'd be nice if someone could point it out to me), but it looks like you can use Promises to make sure the GoogleAuth instance is ready.  Here's what I did to get a consistent result:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {

  gapi.auth2.init({

    client_id: 'my_client_info.apps.googleusercontent.com',

  }).then(function(){

    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get()); //now this always returns correctly        

  });
});
```