# PHP project with google API and javascript: Inherited Mess

Tags: javascript, php, google-people-api

So I have inherited a few projects at work that user php. I have no experience using php so of course have been struggling to fix a problem we found. At this point I am simply just trying to get the google id of who ever happens to be logged in when they visit the site. Weird thing is that some of the time my code works great and i get the google id, but it only works for some of the accounts we have tried, others just return null. The code below I am just trying to get who is signed in right, but I am so ignorant of how this all works that I can't tell what's wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Career Opportunities</title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function startUp(onSuccess, onFailure) {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: 'API KEY',
        clientId: 'CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: 'profile',
      }).then(function() {
        var x = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        console.log("gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() : " + x);
   console.log("userId is : " + x.currentUser.get().getId());

        gapi.client.load('people', 'v1', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.people.people.get({
            'resourceName': 'people/me',
            'requestMask.includeField': 'person.phone_numbers,person.organizations,person.email_addresses,person.names'
          });
          console.log('request: ' + request);
          request.execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);

          });
        });
      });

    }
    gapi.load('client', startUp);
  </script>


  <script src="js/validation.js" async defer></script>



</head>

<body>



</body>

</html>
```

This is the error i get when it doesn't like the user for whatever reason. EDIT: This error is in the console. This page does nothing but show me who is logged in via the console.log.

code:401

data:undefined

error:{code: 401, data: undefined, message: "The request does not have valid authentication credentials."}

message:"The request does not have valid authentication credentials."

**proto**:Object

I have tried so many different things that I assume this code will be a conglomeration of a bunch of different approaches, sorry lol.

EDIT- Added more console.logs - edited above code to reflect this

```
bobtest.php:101 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() : [object Object]
bobtest.php:102 userId is : null
bobtest.php:108 request: [object Object]
cb=gapi.loaded_0:148 GET https://content-people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?requestMask.includeField=person.phone_numbers&key=401 ()
zu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:148
n @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:148
Cu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:123
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
postMessage (async)
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
setTimeout (async)
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:134
l @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:195
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:194
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
postMessage (async)
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
setTimeout (async)
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:131
_.Xj.Rl @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
_.Xj.kc @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
window.startup @ proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.tZDXb_qbHrc.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%:8
(anonymous) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
ba @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:3
b @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
Y.r.(anonymous function) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
Y.x.(anonymous function) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:11
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
bobtest.php:110 {code: 401, data: undefined, message: "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.", error: {…}}
```

**EDIT 3**  Added more console.logs

```
----STARTING CLIENT.INIT
bobtest.php:101 ----CLIENT.INIT SUCCESSFUL
bobtest.php:103 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() : [object Object]
bobtest.php:104 userId is : null
bobtest.php:110 ----CLIENT.LOAD SUCCESSFUL
bobtest.php:111 request: [object Object]
cb=gapi.loaded_0:148 GET https://content-people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?requestMask.includeField=person.phone_numbers%2Cperson.organizations%2Cperson.email_addresses%2Cperson.names&key=AIzaSyATLxJElwrDoYaBJtcWCOOP4JI7CUKlXUk 401 ()
zu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:148
n @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:148
Cu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:123
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
postMessage (async)
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
setTimeout (async)
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:134
l @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:195
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:194
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:126
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:122
postMessage (async)
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
setTimeout (async)
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:119
call @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:131
_.Xj.Rl @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
_.Xj.kc @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
window.startup @ proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.tZDXb_qbHrc.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOgQjGru3ruZo70XwAerRmnfOfOeA:8
(anonymous) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
ba @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:3
b @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
Y.r.(anonymous function) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:10
Y.x.(anonymous function) @ googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup:11
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
bobtest.php:113 ----REQUEST.EXECUTE CALLBACK
bobtest.php:114 {code: 401, data: undefined, message: "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.", error: {…}}
```

**EDIT 4** Added the successful console log

```
----STARTING CLIENT.INIT

bobtest.php:101 ----CLIENT.INIT SUCCESSFUL
bobtest.php:103 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() : [object Object]
bobtest.php:104 userId is : 9999(actually shows id, just removed just in case)
bobtest.php:110 ----CLIENT.LOAD SUCCESSFUL
bobtest.php:111 request: [object Object]
bobtest.php:113 ----REQUEST.EXECUTE CALLBACK
bobtest.php:114 {resourceName: "people/9999999", etag: "%999999=", names: Array(1), emailAddresses: Array(1), result: {…}}
```

Comment: Does this error show in your browser console (which would indicate a problem in javascript), or on the page that is has loaded (which would indicate a php problem)?

Comment: Sorry should of specified. In the console. console.log(resp); is what does it. this page does nothing but show me in the console who is logged in, well its supposed to.

Comment: Thus Alex's comment, this is all javascript, no php seems involved. First thing I would do is put more console.log messages in various places throughout the code, so you can try to pinpoint where exactly the code fails, and what values of variables are when it does. Copy the new code and console output here in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find this answer, my coworker did, but i figured I should post what we ended up getting to work.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id': myClientId,
            'scope': 'email',
            'immediate': true
        }, function(authResult) {
            if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
                gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
                    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId': 'me'});
                    request.execute(function(resp) {

                        var userId = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?>';

                        if(userId == resp.id) {
                            onSuccess();
                        }
                        else {
                            onFailure();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                onFailure();
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of continuing through comments, I'll make some suggestions here and edit as you edit your question.

First of all, please copy the output of your console to your question. This will help us see what is happening thus far in the code.

**edit 4:**

I'm not familiar with the google apis you're working with, so my best advice would be test this code and if it returns logged in = true sometimes and false other times, ask a new question on stackoverflow with this simplified code. Tag it with javascript and google api (whatever the main tag is for it). Looking at answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/33380879/3650835 your code is quite different. So my guess now is that the api calls you make need to be rewritten/aren't being called in the correct order. But give this simplified code a try, does it show signed in sometimes, sometimes not? If so, then we have narrowed down the problem enough for you to ask and probably get a response from someone really familiar with the google apis.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Career Opportunities</title>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    gapi.load('client', startUp);

    function startUp(onSuccess, onFailure) {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: 'API KEY',
        clientId: 'CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: 'profile',
      }).then(function() {
        // here we log whether the user is signed in or not, and it changes unexpectedly
        var x = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        console.log(x.isSignedIn.get());
      });
    }
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eh that validation,js doesnt do anything and shouldn't even be there. didnt notice it was still there. still getting "The request does not have valid authentication credentials."

Comment: Added the successful console.log jsut in case taht helps

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. As far as I can tell the only difference between a success X and a failure X is that the isSignedIn is set to false in one and true in the other. My api key and client Id are correct as well.

Comment: Ok I'd search the webs for that, sounds like that is the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378710/google-sign-in-api-issignedin-get-returning-inconsistent-values maybe Also, obviously make sure the user is signed in to google when testing

Comment: Just giving a small update, have tried lots of stuff since we last talked and nothing has changed. Would update code, but its not working still so why.

Comment: @Darkwingduck every time the error occurs, is `isSignedIn` false? If so, that's got to be the problem, and we can look more into that

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it is always false when it can't get the logged in user.

Comment: @Darkwingduck ok another update with more stripped down code. Something like this, as minimal as possible, if you have to ask another question to find a google api expert really helps in getting answers