# Google OAuth disconnect, signOut but GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get() = true?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-authentication

Here is my code:

function googleLogOut() {

```
debugAlert("googleLogOut:Begin");

GoogleAuth.disconnect();
GoogleAuth.signOut().then(function () {
    debugAlert("googleLogOut:Logout Completed, current login status = " + GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get());
    userNotLoggedIn();
    debugAlert("googleLogOut:Exit");
});
```

}

According to my understanding, the disconnect revokes the authorization which the currently signed-in user has granted to my application and the signOut should log the user out of his Google account, basically backing out the OAuth signin which the user went through originally in order to gain access to my application.

However, immediately after GoogleAuth.signOut(), GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get() evaluates to true - see alert dialog image:

[Alert Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdh0x.png)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378710/google-sign-in-api-issignedin-get-returning-inconsistent-values/33380879

Comment: That issue is the flip side of mine. That user was experiencing that isSignedIn.get() was returning false and this was because his tests were outside of the promised return. Moving the test inside of the promised return solve that issue. In my case, the test for isSignedIn.get() is *inside* the promise so signOut should have fully executed by the time the promise executes and therefore isSignedIn.get() should be returning false. (My current code is already constructed in line with the answer over there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a completely different way to do this. I found this to be much more reliable.

logoutWindow = window.open("https://accounts.google.com/SignOutOptions", "_blank", "toolbar=no,width=600,height=400");

I just open a window to Google's account management page. When the user signs out, they are signed out from my application as well.

As the icing on the cake, when I trap the user logged out event in my application I close the window - if the user is logging out through a window which my application has invoked:

```
try {
    logoutWindow.close();
}
catch (err) {
    // nothing...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as it turns out, the user is still logged in to his Google account so technically isSignedIn.get() is returning the correct value. I confirmed this by opening a new browser tab and going to gmail - clearly I was still logged in. More to the point though, what this code does is revoke all of the permissions which the user has granted to my application - that is the essence of this logout function. To test this -

GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE) == false

So the compound test for whether a Google account is logged in to my application is:

GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get() == true && GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE) == true

Here's the modified logout function. (Same functionality, just modified the debug statements to show the revocation of the scopes privileges.)

function googleLogOut() {

```
debugAlert("googleLogOut:Begin");

GoogleAuth.disconnect();
GoogleAuth.signOut().then(function () {
    debugAlert("googleLogOut:Logout Completed, current login status = " + GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get());
    if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
        debugAlert("googleLogOut:Logout Completed, current SCOPE status = " + GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE));
    }
    userNotLoggedIn();
    debugAlert("googleLogOut:Exit");
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(listener)](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinlistenlistener) - when your listener is called the state of GoogleAuth objects has already been updated.